# How can I get R to modify this matrix in place after a call to fastLmPure?

Tags: r, rcpp, lm, rcpparmadillo, refcounting

I'm trying to run `fastLmPure` in a loop, avoiding copying a large matrix.

I've pre-allocated the matrix to the size I need, and it's only the last column I need to change values in. i.e. it doesn't grow.

I've boiled it down to the minimal cases below, which illustrate the problem I'm having.

I expect the modification of matrix to be done in-place, but instead I get a copy because ref counter has been incremented by the call out to Rcpp.

**`Rcpp` doesn't modify X, so why does an extra refcount hang around, which causes R to make a copy when I next modify?**

**How can I get a modify-in-place after execution returns from fastLm?**

(I'm using R 4.1.2, and running via console to avoid any RStudio env pane reference issues.)

*Example 1:*

```
library(RcppArmadillo)
minimal_fastLm <- function() {
  y <- c(1,2)

  X <- matrix(data = c(1,1,2,3), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
  .Internal(inspect(X))

  model <- .Call("_RcppArmadillo_fastLm_impl", X, y, PACKAGE = "RcppArmadillo")
  .Internal(inspect(X))

  X[, 2] <- c(3,4)
  .Internal(inspect(X))
}

minimal_fastLm()
```

*Gives output (edited for clarity):*

Address unchanged through call to fastLm, but ref count increased, then copy made on modify. (See **bold**).

`@0x0000000017401560 14 REALSXP g0c3 [REF(1),ATT] (len=4, tl=0) 1,1,2,3
...
@0x0000000017401560 14 REALSXP g0c3 [REF(2),ATT] (len=4, tl=0) 1,1,2,3
...
@0x00000000174ad568 14 REALSXP g0c3 [REF(1),ATT] (len=4, tl=0) 1,1,3,4
...`

*Example 2:*
Even more minimal (pure Rcpp)

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('int rawSEXP(SEXP X) { return(1); }')
cppFunction('int asNumMat(NumericMatrix X) { return(1); }')

pureRcpp <- function() {
  X <- matrix(data = c(1,1,2,3), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
  .Internal(inspect(X))

  X[, 2] <- c(4,5)    # Initially modifies in place because X has REF(1).
  .Internal(inspect(X))

  rawSEXP(X)          # Call Rcpp function with raw SEXP
  .Internal(inspect(X))

  X[, 2] <- c(6,7)    # Still modifies in place because X has REF(1).
  .Internal(inspect(X))

  asNumMat(X)         # Call Rcpp function that casts to NumericMatrix
  .Internal(inspect(X))

  X[, 2] <- c(8,9)    # Causes a copy because X has REF(3).
  .Internal(inspect(X))

}
pureRcpp()
```

X was never modified by Rcpp. Nor do I want it to be. I just want to read data.
**So why was ref counter not decremented back to 1 when NumericMatrix went out of scope?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I found that there's some cleaning up that Rcpp could be doing, but isn't.

Raised as a bug, with solution identified.
Will be fixed in the next release of Rcpp.
https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/pull/1205

So, the answer is:

- This modify-in-place should indeed be possible,
- And it will be after a future release of Rcpp.

Comment: I am not sure I agree with your extrapolations here.

Answer (score 1):

R uses copy-on-write and that doesn't change between the write coming from R or C(++) code -- an updated value is just an updated value.

So you if want mutable non-copied data you may have to manage the data yourself in a *non* R data structure.  A simple Armadillo vector or matrix where you take care not to inherit from R data should do.

Allocate that once, modify values as you please, loop to your heart's content.  That should suit your requirement, unless I misunderstood something.

Comment: Dirk. Thanks for coming back so quick on this.

I think perhaps my understanding of what Rcpp is doing under the hood is a bit lacking here. I've written an even more minimal example and added to the bottom of the question.

Comment: My understanding of the ref counting is that when NumericMatrix goes out of scope it should decrement, but that doesn't seem to be happening.
Consequently, when my code returns to R, I can no longer modify-in-place.
The cast to NumericMatrix makes a reference that never goes away.

I assume this is by design, but isn't what I expected

Comment: Glad it helps.  Please feel free to upvote (click on 'up'-triangle) and/or accept (click on 'tick' sign) the answer.   Details on R memory management and internals are in the manuals which you can also read here in a prettier form:  https://rstudio.github.io/r-manuals/

Comment: Apologies, but I think my fundamental question remains unanswered (although entirely possible I've just missed the key info in your response)...  Why does the ref count stay above 1 after NumericMatrix goes out of scope?

Comment: Please see the language internals manuals for these matters. I think you are mostly confused and think you have an Rcpp question when what you really ponder are R internals.  We do not change that, we just play along and use the nice framework R offers us.  Hope this helps.